# Use rest api to assign a signer that is a companyUser

Tags: docusignapi

Right now when creating an envelope, I am unable to designate any other Company Users as signers.

Is there a way to create an envelope via the API and make one of the Signers the an Company user?

This is the signers enclosed in the inline template

```
  "recipients":{
    "signers":[
    {
    "name":"MoCkVotEr testpass",
    "email":"kevin+2@joinmosaic.com",
    "accessCode":null,
    "roleName":"Recipient",
    "clientUserId":"a499e405-1385-46fe-9742-b338c2a5d3b2",
    "recipientId":"1",
    "tabs":{
        "textTabs":[
            {
                "tabLabel":"\\*loanAgreementId",
                "value":"3",
                "tabId":null
            },
            {
                "tabLabel":"\\*borrowerName",
                "value":"MoCkVotEr testpass",
                "tabId":null
            },
            {
                "tabLabel":"\\*accountHolderName",
                "value":"Account Holder",
                "tabId":null
            },
            {
                "tabLabel":"\\*accountNumber",
                "value":"11111111111111111",
                "tabId":null
            },
            {
                "tabLabel":"\\*routingNumber",
                "value":"111111111",
                "tabId":null
            },
            {
                "tabLabel":"\\*bankName",
                "value":"asdf",
                "tabId":null
            }
        ],
        "checkboxTabs":[
            {
                "tabLabel":"\\*isCheckingAccount",
                "selected":true,
                "tabId":null
            },
            {
                "tabLabel":"\\*isSavingsAccount",
                "selected":false,
                "tabId":null
            }
        ],
        "titleTabs":[

        ]
    },
    "routingOrder":null
    },
{
"name":"Kevin",
"email":"kevin@joinmosaic.com",
"accessCode":null,
"roleName":"Mosaic",
"clientUserId":"MosaicSignator",
"userId":"3103274b-89ac-4f0c-8f4a-c92a9d2f3749",
"status":"created",
"recipientId":"2",
"tabs":{
    "textTabs":[

    ],
    "checkboxTabs":[

    ],
    "titleTabs":[

    ]
},
"routingOrder":null
}
]
}
```

This is the result when requesting recipients from the envelope

```
{
    "signers": [

        {
            "name": "Kevin",
            "email": "kevin@joinmosaic.com",
            "recipientId": "2",
            "recipientIdGuid": "818293ec-ba4a-4adf-941d-3119740e62eb",
            "requireIdLookup": "false",
            "userId": "**3da53563-5c29-488f-8527-aa5913b004c0**",
            "clientUserId": "MosaicSignator",
            "routingOrder": "3",
            "note": "",
            "roleName": "Mosaic",
            "status": "created",
            "templateLocked": "false",
            "templateRequired": "false"
        },
        {
            "name": "MoCkVotEr testpass",
            "email": "kevin+2@joinmosaic.com",
            "recipientId": "1",
            "recipientIdGuid": "ebb98be0-b1bd-446d-ac79-b7b38b63199c",
            "requireIdLookup": "false",
            "userId": "12f73115-5cb2-4a51-84b3-640a89915b61",
            "clientUserId": "a499e405-1385-46fe-9742-b338c2a5d3b2",
            "routingOrder": "1",
            "note": "",
            "roleName": "Recipient",
            "status": "sent",
            "templateLocked": "false",
            "templateRequired": "false"
        }
    ],
    "agents": [],
    "editors": [],
    "intermediaries": [],
    "carbonCopies": [],
    "certifiedDeliveries": [],
    "inPersonSigners": [],
    "recipientCount": "3",
    "currentRoutingOrder": "1"
}
```

This is my user from the /account/{}/users api call

```
{
    "userName": "Kevin xxxxx",
    "userId": "**3103274b-89ac-4f0c-8f4a-c92a9d2f3749**",
    "userType": "CompanyUser",
    "userStatus": "Active",
    "uri": "/users/3103274b-89ac-4f0c-8f4a-c92a9d2f3749"
}
```

As you can see the two UserIds do not match. However when going through the GUIConsole They do match.

Comment: Why aren't you able to set the email/name for your signers, what error do you get?  Or what stops you from setting them?  And where is this happening, in the DocuSign Console?  You can definitely both through the Console and through the API if you are coding something up...

Comment: I am able to use Email/Name however it generates a new "user" rather than using the ones already used with docusign.. Example Below

Answer (score 0):

The DocuSign system will only recognize recipients and match them to their existing DS accounts if all their info is the same as the account user.  This definitely includes their `email`, `name`, and `userId`, but might contain other aspects too such as a `clientUserId` (if you are using Embedded functionality).

To figure out what is different with these users you can make the *Get Envelope Recipient Status* API call, which will return the above info (plus more) for each recipient.  You can then go through and make sure all the IDs, emails, etc. are what you expect.

Check out this API Walkthrough for making the call:
http://iodocs.docusign.com/APIWalkthrough/getEnvelopeRecipientStatus